# Typeahead fetch data from url json value not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

Below is my HTML code for angular typeahead:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <select name="" class="form-control" ng-model="city" ng-change="onChange(e)" id="city">
    <option value="DELHI">DELHI</option>
    <option value="BANGALORE">BANGALORE</option>
    <option value="GOA">GOA</option>
    <option value="KOLKATA">KOLKATA</option>
    <option value="PUNJAB">PUNJAB</option>
 </select>
</div>

<input type="search" name="" ng-model="bankName" typeahead='bank_name as bankName | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8'  id="input" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Search" required="required" title="">

<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>IFSC</th>
            <th>BANK ID</th>
            <th>BANK NAME</th>
            <th>BRANCH</th>
            <th>ADDRESS</th>
            <th>CITY</th>
            <th>DISTRICT</th>
            <th>STATE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="service in services">
            <td>{{service.ifsc}}</td>
            <td>{{service.bank_id}}</td>
            <td>{{service.bank_name}}</td>
            <td>{{service.branch}}</td>
            <td>{{service.address}}</td>
            <td>{{service.city}}</td>
            <td>{{service.district}}</td>
            <td>{{service.state}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Below is JS File:

```
var app = angular.module('bankBranch', ['ui.bootstrap'])


.controller('ServicesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.bankUrl = "https://someweb.com/api/bank_branches?offset=0&limit=50&city=";
    $scope.city = 'BANGALORE';
    var bankName = '$scope.bank_name';  
    var cities = '$scope.city';
    $scope.getdata = function(){
        $http.get($scope.bankUrl+$scope.city).then(function(response){
            $scope.services = response.data;
        });
    }

    $scope.onChange = function(e){
        $scope.getdata();
    }
    $scope.getdata();
}]);
```

The problem is I am trying to fetch the branch name in the input field and as I type the below table data should get filtered according to that. The onChange function is working for select box. The JSON format of the api url is as follows:

```
[{
"ifsc": "asdads",
"bank_id": 110,
"bank_name": "abc bank",
"branch": "BANGALORE",
"address": "ewrwerewr",
"city": "BANGALORE",
"district": "BANGALORE URBAN",
"state": "KARNATAKA"
}]
```

Any Idea how to modify this? Getting stuck. Please help me.

Comment: @zmbq you edited my code do you know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you using typeahead from AngularJS UI Bootstrap [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#typeahead)? If so you need to change `typeahead` to `uib-typeahead` in your search input tag

Comment: @zmbq Yeah I am using this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistaken while using typeahead directive, the way it works is, it will need a promise object on which you will apply `$viewValue` filter

```
<input type="search" name="" ng-model="bankName" 
   typeahead='bank_name for bankName in getdata()'
   id="input" class="form-control" value="" 
   placeholder="Search" required="required" title=""/>
```

So lets change your `$scope.getData` function to return promise object from it.

```
$scope.getdata = function(){
    return $http.get($scope.bankUrl+$scope.city).then(function(response){
        $scope.services = response.data;
        return $scope.services;
    });
}

$scope.onChange = function(e){
    return $scope.getdata();
}
```

> **Note:** If you are using Angular ui-bootstrap version 1.X+ then you have to use `uib-` prefix before each ui-bootstrap directive like in your case it would be `uib-typeahead` instead of `typeahead`.

Comment: I am using this <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.1.4/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>

Comment: @PreetySingh you have to use `uib-typeahead` then. :)

Comment: error in console :( Argument 'ServicesCtrl' is not a function, got string

Comment: Are you sure you have referred JS file on html page?

Comment: Check if you have mistakenly remove some your JS reference, open browser console "Sources" tab & check does your desired file has been loaded or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124119/discussion-between-preety-singh-and-pankaj-parkar).